# def assign_members(x1, x2, centers)

Tags: python, machine-learning, colors, k-means

The following code is from kmeans machine learning, could some one kindly explain those code?

```
colors_map = np.array(['b', 'r'])

def assign_members(x1, x2, centers):

    compare_to_first_center = np.sqrt(np.square(np.array(x1) - centers[0][0]) + np.square(np.array(x2) - centers[0][1]))
    
    compare_to_second_center = np.sqrt(np.square(np.array(x1) - centers[1][0]) + np.square(np.array(x2) - centers[1][1]))
    
    class_of_points = compare_to_first_center > compare_to_second_center
    
    colors = colors_map[class_of_points + 1 - 1]
    
    return colors, class_of_points
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is based on showing your code, telling them whats not working and what you already have tried. Questions like this will probably never get a respond. It's sad but the truth..

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, if someone can answer, will be a big surprise, if not, C'est la vie :-) Will try to figure out anyway.